# Is it possible to create programatically Multiple Buttons in an aspx page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

What I want is for the user to type say 3 into a textbox which will then create 3 buttons on the aspx page, is this possible on the webpage or is it just for windows apps? So depending on what the user puts in the textbox, i want to display that number i.e. if they type 4 in textbox then i want 4 buttons to appear
My code is below:

```
Button btnSave = new Button();
btnSave.ID = "btnSave";
btnSave.Text = "Save";
```

Comment: well your code is creating buttons not textboxes, but yes it is possible. Just create textboxes and add them to the page.

Comment: Oh sorry yeah doh! Im not sure how to add them to the page though

Comment: `this.Controls.Add(btnSave)`; but that's not all; if you attach events :D ...you guessed right, more pain is coming ;) (depending on _where_ you are adding that control to the page)

Comment: Do not forget to give different ID on each button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add these to your ASPX page

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" />
<asp:Panel ID="buttonPanel" runat="server"></asp:Panel>
```

and then in your Button click event:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int number = int.Parse(TextBox1.Text);
    for(int i =  0; i< number ;i++)
    {
        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.ID = "btnSave" + i;
        btn.Text = "Save " + i;
        buttonPanel.Controls.Add(btn);
    }
}
```

You can use `int.TryParse` to check for invalid inputs in the TextBox.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a detailed example on

**[Adding Controls to an ASP.NET form Dynamically](http://learning2code.net/Learn/2009/8/12/Adding-Controls-to-an-ASPNET-form-Dynamically.aspx)**

What they do in that example is to create a **PlaceHolder** control called **DynamicControlsHolder** where some controls are added when the user clicks on the **AddControlButton**

```
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <asp:Button ID="AddControlButton" runat="server" Text="Add Control" onclick="AddControlButton_Click" />
    <br />
    <asp:PlaceHolder ID="DynamicControlsHolder" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
    <br />
    <br />
    <asp:Button ID="Submit" runat="server" Text="Submit Form" onclick="Submit_Click" />
    <br />
    ........
    </div>
    </form>
```

And then in the code behind they react to the **AddControlButton** being clicked

```
 protected void AddControlButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox txt = new TextBox();
    DynamicControlsHolder.Controls.Add(txt);
    DynamicControlsHolder.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br>"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way :

```
for(int i=1; i<= ButtonNos; i++)
{
 Button NewButton =new Button();
 NewButton.ID = "Newbutton"+i;
 NewButton.Width = 540;
 NewButton.Height = 60;
 NewButton.Text = "Button "+ i;

 this.Controls.Add(NewButton);
}
```

Comment: I think you wanted to write `NewButton.Text = "Button "+ i;`